# Domain network - DC cannot access Internet (nor can clients when wired-only)

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2008, domain

I am not well versed in networking in general but went ahead and attempted to convert my home workgroup in a domain. The domain controller (Win Server 2008) shows no errors in dcdiag, and machines can join to domain successfully. The DC has no wireless capability and is connected my **WRT54G** router.

My problem is that the DC has no access to the internet - for example, it cannot ping 8.8.8.8). I believe this is not an issue with the DC itself, as any client machine, when are wire-connected only, do not have internet access. However, when client machines connect to the network wirelessly internet works ok. It's like when wired the network is isolated and the wireless is some sort of DMZ... I may be saying something stupid, I don't know.

Anyway, what could cause this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `WRT54G` has a feature called `AP Isolation` located on the `Wireless -> Advanced Settings` page. It is also known as `client isolation` as it will prevent `client to client` connections. 
**If this is the case, `Disable` this feature.**

- Check whether `default gateway : 192.168.1.1` is reachable in
  wired-only scenario.
- Check whether `wireless IP : 192.168.1.x` ping `wired-only IP :
    192.168.1.120` and vice versa.
- Check whether `Wireless & Wired IP Configuration` are `AUTO` or
  `MANUAL`. If you set `Default Gateway` for both adapter, it wont able
  to work with `Wireless Wired` together.
- Try Setting both `Wireless and Wired` `AUTO (DHCP)` and check what
  response you get.
- Take `backup of WRT54G's settings`, and `Factory Restore` it.

**Do some trial and error accordingly, this should work!**